# Showing multiple badges awarded in help center

Tags: feature-request, badges, help-center

Recently, the [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) in the help center was upgraded.
Although it shows nice and clear **which** badges were earned by me, it does not show **how many** badges were awarded.
For instance, if I have earned two "nice question" badeges, it only shows the badge was awarded to me, but it does not show that I have earned it twice.

Is it possible to add a counter on the badges help center to show **how many** badges were earned?

For example:
[image]

> ```
>                    ^
>                    |
>                    +-- like this
> ```

Comment: But why would you need that? It's already on your profile page. I see very little added value here, but well, maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Mołot - I agree this feature is not critical (to put it mildly). But if the information regarding what badges I already earned is there - why not showing all the relevant information?

Comment: For speed. Showing ones you have lets you skip them when you are looking what to earn next. Earning badges requires useful actions,  so CPU time is spent for site's benefit. What's benefit of showing number?

Comment: Interesting idea, I would add this as part of the green checkmark tooltip though e.g. "you've earned this badge 57 times". Otherwise it would be confusing.

Comment: By the way, are you familiar with [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question?userid=1714410)?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - (1) the tooltip idea sounds very nice. (2) I am familiar with that page, but I was thinking of making the information more accessible and visible without clicking and back-ing for each badge...